Need help Implementing Apple ID login in my react native expo project
I'm pretty new to React Native and I'm currently working on adding Apple ID login functionality using expo-apple-authentication in my project. The first time a user logs in, I can successfully retrieve their email and full name. However, due to security reasons and other requirements, I don't get this info on subsequent logins.
This leads me to my main concern: I understand that I should store this info on my backend, but what happens if a user decides to delete their account? I thought about marking records as 'deleted' in my database instead of actually removing them, but I'm not comfortable with the idea of keeping user data indefinitely due to legal and ethical issues.
Does anyone know if there’s a way to completely disassociate a user’s data from the app via Apple ID, without having to do it manually? Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated, especially considering I'm still learning the ropes here!
Thanks in advance!
Try to implement Apple ID in my react native expo project

You have to delete the data https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/708415

How can I do this in react native expo I couldn’t find any implementation

you just need to delete the user data, apple tester will test delete and reenter the same user id, if it shows there's user already exists your app will be considered as not completed app.

Apple only provides return data full name and email once. So, for testing development you have remove data app from icloud:
Setting > iCloud > Sign-in & Security > Sign in with Apple > Remove App
and then sign out icloud and sign in again.
Go to your app and sign in with apple again, it will provide email and full name again.
